# Is it conceivable to make a game in system.drawing?

Tags: c#, graphics

a while ago I started making simple game in c#, however after some time i started to add more and more objects on the screen and sadly i saw my framerate  geting realy slow.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1200, 700);
Graphics FrameGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

while (true)
{

    FrameGraphics.Clear(Color.White);

    foreach (GraphicalObject S in ObjectControll.ToList())
    {
        FrameGraphics.DrawImage(S.picture, (float)S.X, (float)S.Y);
    }
    DrawHandle.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
    frames++;
}
```

why most 3D games run faster than this loop with 20 objects in it? Do I need to use any software to make a game?

Comment: To make "real" games people generally use premade game engines, or physics engines. These have a bunch of code already made for you that you can use instead of having to start from complete scratch.

Comment: "Is it conceivable to make a game in system.drawing" - no it's not.

Comment: @coinbird my target is mostly to polish my programing skills, not to make a "real" game but I cannot continue if I can't get more than 20 objects on the screen. I arledy have done most of the phicics made myself and I like it that way.

Comment: This is a broad area. Simple games (like sinking ships or so) may run well the way you are intending to do it. Most games take advantage of  hardware graphic acceleration by using Direct3D and that like. WPF graphics would have this included. Still real professional game programmers mostly have their own "game engines", which are wrapping away a lot of things related to 3D graphics calculation...

Comment: `System.Drawing` is relatively slow, due to it essentially being a wrapper against GDI+ (and probably going through COM). I suggest picking up something like MonoGame to make a simple 2D game.

Comment: You can get a very simple x10 speedup by paying attention to the pixel format of the bitmap.  Using 32bppPArgb is essential to avoid the extra cost of converting the bitmap to the video frame buffer format.

Comment: @willaien Thank you, personally i dislike anything more than built in libraries, for this project I need nothing more than drawing an image, rotating it and scaling. Can you get these functions directly from GDI+ or would it be possible to make my own Drawing library?

Comment: You're not going to be able to use just built-in libraries for this in a performant way. You can try using something like `ImageSharp`, then output the image generated to whatever control you're using for output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly create a game using System.Drawing, however it's not really what it's designed for and with a complex game and a lot of objects I imagine you will run into problems.

Your best bet is to use something that is the correct tool for the job and designed for games. Look into something like [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn759441.aspx), or personally I have found the [XNA framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200104.aspx) very easy to get into as a C# programmer, although it is unsupported and has been superseded by [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/).

Comment: Since XNA is dead, I strongly recommend either FXA or MonoGame instead.

Comment: You're right @AdamSears, it's been a long time since I've dabbled in making games.

Comment: The only reason I even remembered is because of how sad I was when XNA was killed :(